# SQL Client error on some devices but works on other

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-mobile, sqlclient, .net-cf-3.5

I'm connecting a Windows Mobile to MsSql server 2005 using System.SqlClient It works great on some devices but not on other.

May it be a issue on the database?

This error happens when I try to execute a reader. the Open does success.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: SqlException
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadNetlib(Int32 bytesExpected)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ProcessSSPI(Int32 receivedLength)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior run, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InternalClose(Boolean closeReader)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the SQL Colletion that made the problem.